# Autodiscover cannot find EMailAddress

Tags: activesync

I have no idea why my xml id wrong. It has been taken from MSDN's example.

I send such xml to autodiscover of outlook.com

```
   <Autodiscover
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/autodiscover/outlook/requestschema/2006">
    <Request>
    <EMailAddress>bhychik@live.com</EMailAddress>
       <AcceptableResponseSchema>
         http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/autodiscover/outlook/responseschema/2006a
        </AcceptableResponseSchema>
     </Request>
    </Autodiscover>
```

But in answer i got:

```
<Autodiscover xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/autodiscover/responseschema/2006">
   <Response xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/autodiscover/mobilesync/responseschema/2006">
         <Error Time="19:23:03.4991841" Id="0">
             <ErrorCode>600</ErrorCode>
             <Message>EMailAddress not found in request body</Message>
             <DebugData></DebugData>
         </Error>
     </Response>
</Autodiscover>
```

What is wrong with my request?

Comment: m also facing same issue for xyz@outlook.com. if you find any solution then please let us know here.